# Pressing tab after "sout" expands to only "out.println()" without "System"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Pressing tab after `sout` live template does not work on my PC. It prints only `out.println()`.

[image: output not come]

Answer (score 3):

You have the `System` class statically imported, so this behavior is expected. Remove the static import if you want a fully qualified class name in the code.

The imports style to use can be changed at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Imports.